# Perl - mechanize

Tags: perl, screen-scraping

I have the following code that works just fine.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use LWP 6.03;
    use URI;

    my $browser=LWP::UserAgent->new;

    my $url=URI->new ( 'http://www.google.com/search');

    $url->query_form(
        'h1'=>'en',
        'num'=>'100',
        'q'=>'glass',
    );

    my $response=$browser->get($url,
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/4.76 [en] (win98; U)',
        'Accept' => 'image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,image/png,*/*',
        'Accept-Charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
    );

    if ($response->content=~m/glass/i){
        print "Success";
        open (GGLASS,">gglass");
        print GGLASS $response->content;
    } else {
        print "complete failure";
    }
```

I have another piece of code that also works fine.
It uses the following:

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl -w
     use strict;
     use WWW::Mechanize;
     use HTML::TokeParser;
```

When I look up the documentation for my code at cpan it tells me that the libraries I am using are deprecated.  Even though it works with my system, the style of programming is being abandoned.  It references me to something I have never used and I do not know if that is soon to be abandoned as well.  What is the popular way to scrape a website.  I do not want to be considered a dinosaur or be stuck with antiquated or remedial programs and tactics that leave me in the previous century.  If you could come up with a piece of code that is similar to the first example that would be nice.  This way I could compare the two.

Comment: Care to provide a link to the doc blurp that says your code is deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentation is wrong. Neither one of LWP, URI, WWW::Mechanize, HTML::TokeParser is deprecated. Mechanize works just fine in general for crawling. I would replace HTML::TokeParser with something that handles HTML parsing in a declarative fashion, though - [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) is splendid, [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) is nice.

However, concerning your code example: Google's terms of use forbid scraping. Use [their API](http://code.google.com/more/#google-search) instead!

Comment: Using Selenium is a good idea when: 1. You want a standard interface, i.e. WebDriver, that can be accessed from outside of Perl. 2. You want backends that are not LWP, e.g. chromedriver, phantomjs or Java HtmlUnit.